# How can i scrape the lowest absolute position on the left of a span among of a div

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

As an intern, I have to **scrape** the price of a product sheet on a site. But the div contains multiple spans with prices and only one contains the actual price that is displayed. Their absolute left position changes with each refresh. So when I do something like
`$productPrice $packtPageXpath->query('//div[@class="bloc_price"]'); if ($productPrice->length > 0) { $productSheet['name'] = $productPrice->item(0)->nodeValue;`
this returns me the list of all the prices in a different order at each refresh in the array

Here is an example of a product sheet
https://www.pompes-direct.com/pompage/pompe-electrique/surface/jet/jet-102-t/4432.html

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Comment: Looks like they _deliberately_ tried to make what you want to do there harder, by providing multiple different prices, and randomly positioning them. So that probably means, you should not try and _steal_ that data to begin with, it clearly looks like they don’t want you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensible thing to do is to extract the left position from the appropriate `div` elements in `//div[@id="top_produit"]//div[@class="bloc_price"]/div` by getting the value between "left:" and "px;" in the `style` attributes, comparing all the values in PHP, and using the div with the lowest value.

The less sensible thing to do is assume that they'll never have a real position of 100 or greater or a fake position lower than 100, conclude that since the `style` attributes are otherwise identical one must be shorter than all the others, and write an xpath to find that one.

`//div[@id="top_produit"]//div[@class="bloc_price"]/div[(string-length(@style) =81)]/span[not(contains(@style, "text-decoration:line-through"))]`

Might work!